# How do I send a link to another action in an email?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to send a link in an email for our password reset function. This is the best I came up with yet.

```
string link = string.Format("<a href='{0}://{1}{2}'>Click here.</a>", 
Request.Url.Scheme, Request.Url.Authority, 
Url.Action("ResetPasswordAction", new { passwordToken = token }));
```

Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: Define "more elegant". Why is this not elegant enough?

Comment: This has nothing to do with email. The url will be generated in server side and converted to html anchor tag.

Comment: @KrisVandermotten I expected this to be trivial the same way inserting a link into a view is and my solution feels sort of cobbled together to me.

Comment: @emrenevayeshirazi I'll remove the email-tag.

Comment: When you insert a link into a View, you use relative paths. But, in an email, you need to use absolute paths. So, it cannot be trivial. Your solution looks good to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [HtmlHelper.GenerateRouteLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470368%28v=vs.108%29.aspx)

it should lead to :

```
HtmlHelper.GenerateRouteLink(Request.RequestContext,
                             RouteTable.Routes,
                             "Click here.",
                             targetRouteName,
                             Request.Url.Scheme,
                             Request.Url.Authority,
                             "",
                             new RouteValueDictionary(new { action = "ResetPasswordAction", controller = "YourController", passwordToken = token }),
                             new Dictionary<string, object>()
    );
```

Though I'm not sure it is "more elegant", I hope this will help anyway